# Facebook Multi friend selector

Tags: facebook, request

I'm trying to implement a "challenge a friend" request using the multi friend selector, I've added the following code

```
FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
    title: 'App title',
    message: "Message"
}, function() {
     console.log('callback');
});
```

This shows up the popup to select my friends, but it seems the requests are not being send.

Am I forgetting something here?

Comment: I dont see any problem in your code. Are you having any more quotations which may be conflicting , since you are using double quotes for message only. And to exactly track the problem, did you tried to log the response back from FB in the callback function?

Comment: @Vijay It returns the ID's of all the people I invited, but they don't see the invite, which seems a bit weird.

Comment: it should return a Unique RequestId. You can use the graph api explorer developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/  for checking whether the target users got any application request or not.

Comment: @Vijay It does return a request ID, but it also returns an array with the users you invited.

Comment: Then it's evident that the app requests has been delivered to those user you selected. Did you tried with the GRAPH API Explorer for the target users to verify they got the app request.

Comment: @Vijay I'm not really sure how to check that, does it matter if that user doesn't have the app installed? Shouldn't matter right?

Comment: graph.facebook.com/FB_USER_ID/apprequests?access_token=VALID_ACCESS_TOKEN will return all apprequests the user got. No matter whether the user has installed the application.

Comment: From the looks of it; it seems that the user did not get any requests, the same with other users I tested with.

Comment: Oh, hold on, it appears they did receive those requests ...